# XSSFWorkbook takes a lot of time to load

Tags: java, excel, optimization, apache-poi, xssf

I am using the following code:

```
File file = new File("abc.xlsx");
InputStream st = new FileInputStream(file);
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(st);
```

The xlsx file itself has 25,000 rows and each row has content in 500 columns. During debugging, I saw that the third row where I create a XSSFWorkbook, it takes a lot of time (1 hour!) to complete this statement.

Is there a better way to access the values of the original xlsx file?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First up, don't load a XSSFWorkbook from an InputStream when you have a file! Using an InputStream requires buffering of everything into memory, which eats up space and takes time. Since you don't need to do that buffering, don't!

If you're running with the latest nightly builds of POI, then it's very easy. Your code becomes:

```
File file = new File("C:\\D\\Data Book.xlsx");
OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(file);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);
```

Otherwise, it's very similar:

```
File file = new File("C:\\D\\Data Book.xlsx");
OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(file.getAbsolutePath());
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);
```

Comment: If that does not completely solve the problem, then you can use  poi event api as a low memory footprint way to read a large file. The poi documentation contains an example here: http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api

Comment: Thanks, will try this out. Just curious to know how will this solve the problem? Won't it buffer the contents into memory? Or will it just access the data using the original references by any chance?

Comment: If you open it with a file, less will be buffered than if you open with an inputstream

Comment: This approach is not working for me, my  execution time stops for 5 mins at this line ' XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); ' and then executes the next line

Comment: @akaushik It works for almost everyone else, so it's probably a bug with your system. Do a Java thread dump and see where it is blocking, then fix that

Comment: Changing to File has little difference in memory consumption for me either, relative to FileInputStream.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Streaming version of POI. This will load a subset of the file into memory as needed. It is the recommended method when dealing with large files.

[POI SXSSF](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf)

Comment: My impression is the streaming version of POI only applies to writing files, not reading files.

Comment: Correct, SXSSF is for writing only. To do low memory reading, you need the event (SAX) processing