# Loading an empty .xlsx file with XSSF takes 20 seconds. Why?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I am using the following lines to open an **empty** Excel 2007 document:

```
OPCPackage opcPackage = OPCPackage.openOrCreate(file)
wb = new XSSFWorkbook(opcPackage);
```

The funny thing is, it is taking 20 seconds just to do that. Why?

Others were complaining about XSSF because it is taking too slow to load a huge file. But for me it is just an empty file that should be done in not even 1 second!

Comment: POI has some problems when dealing with XSSF format. It is slow and will eat up an awful lot of memory to open even a 10 MB `.xlsx` file. --- [I have a 141 MB file I'm still unable to open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891851/how-to-load-a-large-xlsx-file-with-apache-poi). --- I suggest evading POI as much as possible when it comes to `.xlsx`files.

Comment: Is the file on a slow remote drive by any chance? And are you sure it's really empty? Loading an almost empty .xlsx file in POI should take well under a second...

Comment: i deleted every single cell but still the same.. at least i know it now that it should load under a second.. probably the file is corrupt?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: I am not sure if the file you're producing is a valid xlsx file. Maybe it takes so long because it is not created as excel workbook.

As for the library efficiency: there is a question somewhere here about fast xlsx writing and poi performs excellently using SXSSF library branch. Not sure if it supports reading though.

Comment: it has been created as an excel 2007 workbook and saved it as .xlsx. but probably it turned corrupt after a while.. i don't know.

Comment: If this is the case, then you could produce a new file using [User api example](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#user_api) from POI webpage. Just replace the `HSSF` constructor with `XSSF` and change the name to `.xlsx`. And make sure you work with latest poi version, 3.8.

Comment: i was working with xssf since the beginning. also, i deleted it and created a new one from the code ive written. perhaps i should try to delete the file and create a new one, but from excel itself. if this works under a second there is an issue with my code.

for the next three days i don't have access to it. i will let you know as soon ill have tried it out.

Comment: i created a new project just to load an empty xlsx-file generated in excel and it still took 20 seconds. then i changed to poi3.9(beta) and it took only 10 seconds.

Comment: doing the same with .xls using new HSSFWorkbook(..): 280 ms

Comment: Interesting finding. Sounds like something to report as a bug.