# Apache POI read a large xlsm file

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I'm using the Apache POI to open and read an excel file (.xlsm) which may contain 1 million rows per sheet. I tried a sample which contains only 8k rows with the tutorials for Apache POI that I found on web but it just takes for ever to open the file and I'm pretty sure that will cause OOM exception later.

Does Apache POI have any API built in to handle excel files with large number of rows such as my case?

I've checked the Apache documentation over SAX API but i wasn't able to understand it fully.

Thanks

Comment: Did you [try reading the Apache POI documentation](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#record_aware_event_api)?

Comment: Which part did you not understand fully?

Comment: If you are talking TBs of data then look into Apache Hadoop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to load a large xlsx file with Apache POI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891851/how-to-load-a-large-xlsx-file-with-apache-poi)