# getting Hyperlink of Cell in Excel File

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I 'am trying to get hyperlink and  label of a cell in Excel file  using this
library (this library is based on apache POI)

https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader#supported-methods

I tried this

```
 InputStream is = new FileInputStream("file");
 Workbook   workbook = StreamingReader.builder().rowCacheSize(100)   
                        .bufferSize(4096)   
                        .open(is);   
 Iterator<Row>    rowIterator=workbook.getSheetAt(0).iterator();
 Row row=rowIterator.next();
 Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
 Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();
 String parthyperlink=currentCell.getHyperlink().getAddress();
 String label=currentCell.getHyperlink().getLabel();
```

but I get this Exception

> com.monitorjbl.xlsx.exceptions.NotSupportedException at
>   com.monitorjbl.xlsx.impl.StreamingCell.getHyperlink(StreamingCell.java:353)
>   at
>   com.z2data.mapping.ExeclHorizental.getCurrentRow(ExeclHorizental.java:88)

Comment: https://github.com/monitorjbl/excel-streaming-reader/blob/master/src/main/java/com/monitorjbl/xlsx/impl/StreamingCell.java#L432

Comment: Why not just use normal Apache POI?

Comment: @Gagravarr because I have large files and depending on this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891851/how-to-load-a-large-xlsx-file-with-apache-poi  I choose excel-streaming-reader

Answer (score 1):

Hyperlink is not a a string. Instantiate a Hyperlink instead. Try this:

```
Hyperlink h = currentCell.getHyperlink();
```

You can then fetch the address of the particular cell

```
if (h == null) {
   System.err.println("Cell didn't have a hyperlink!");
} else {
   System.out.println("Cell : " + h.getLabel() + " -> " + h.getAddress());
}
```

Comment: Is the cell null? Have you tried putting it in a try/catch block?