# How to compare single columned two Excel files which are having 500,000k rows

Tags: java, excel

Goal: Compare two excel files, each excel is having only one column but having half million rows. 
I just want to see the un-common values between two excels.

Column: only 1 
Rows: 500,000

Language: JAVA

What I tried so far:

1. Apache POI used (please see below program-1)
2. ArrayList  (please see below program-2)
3. I tried some websites where we can upload the multiples Excel to see the differences (https://www.textcompare.org/excel/)
4. I increased heap size to 256 to 2048m, but not working for me.

**(My programs are working good for small set of data or few records)**

above efforts did not work for me.

program-1::

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;

public static ExcelReader excel3 = null;
public static ExcelReader excel2 = null;

excel3 = new ExcelReader("C:\\Users\\DataExcelCompare\\Book3.xlsx");
excel2 = new ExcelReader("C:\\Users\\DataExcelCompare\\Book2.xlsx");

    File f3 = new File("C:\\Users\\DataExcelCompare\\Book3.xlsx");      
        FileInputStream fi3 = new FileInputStream(f3);
        Workbook workbook3 = WorkbookFactory.create(fi3);
        Sheet sheet3 = workbook3.getSheet("book3");     

        File f2 = new File("C:\\Users\\DataExcelCompare\\Book2.xlsx");      
        FileInputStream fi2 = new FileInputStream(f2);
        Workbook workbook2 = WorkbookFactory.create(fi2);
        Sheet sheet2 = workbook2.getSheet("book2"); 

         int firstRow2 = sheet2.getFirstRowNum();
         int lastRow2 = sheet2.getLastRowNum();

         int firstRow3 = sheet3.getFirstRowNum();
         int lastRow3 = sheet3.getLastRowNum();

            for(int i=firstRow2; i <= lastRow2; i++) { 
             for(int j=firstRow3; j <= lastRow3; j++) {

                String ele2 = sheet2.getRow(i).getCell(0).toString().trim();
                String ele3 = sheet3.getRow(j).getCell(0).toString().trim() ;

                 if(ele2.toString() !=  ele3.toString())
                 {
                    // some operation 
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    // some operation   
                 }

             }
```

program-2::

```
ArrayList<String> listOne = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> listTwo =new ArrayList<String>();

         for(int i=firstRow2; i <= lastRow2; i++) {
             listOne.add(sheet2.getRow(i).getCell(0).toString().trim());
             System.out.println("added: " + sheet2.getRow(i).getCell(0).toString().trim());
         }

         for(int j=firstRow3; j <= lastRow3; j++) {
             listTwo.add(sheet3.getRow(j).getCell(0).toString().trim());
             System.out.println("added: " + sheet3.getRow(j).getCell(0).toString().trim());
         }

            listTwo.removeAll(listOne);

            System.out.println("list two : " + listTwo);
```

Comment: Use a program like SAS - will handle that amount of data easily...

Comment: @SolarMike any other details about SAS ? any site or link ? thanks for your comment.

Comment: SAS is easy to find...

Comment: **My** google fu is strong: https://www.sas.com/de_ch/solutions/analytics.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjw0pfzBRCOARIsANi0g0v9sgjBh7wtbRdDR9wRqaJsOgej6VQQxZ64AgEdQdfBat_TC-ezE1IaAqg5EALw_wcB

Comment: Have a look at the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891851/how-to-load-a-large-xlsx-file-with-apache-poi

Answer (score 0):

Reading Excel files using Apache POI is extremely memory intensive.

Memory errors when working with Excel files with less than 50,000 rows is not uncommon (let alone 500,000 x 2).

It's never going to work.

Find a 3rd party program to convert those Excel files to .txt's before they reach your Java program.